# How to do a fast table inequality inference in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have to create an inequality 2D  table mapping.

```
   # a is a 2D np array, ix  and jx are given
   for i in range(9) :
      for j in range(9) :
         if (a[i,j] <  ix <= a[i+1,j])   and  (a[i,j] <  jx <= a[i,j+1])  :
            return a[i+1, j+1]
```

Is there a faster way (ie using dict in python) that looping on Ni x Nj array values ?

Comment: So this returns as soon as it encounters the particular condition?  You can perform the tests for the whole array, `(a[:-1]<ix) & (ix<=a[1:])` etc, but that does test all values.  Depending on where the condition is satisfied that might be slower than your loop, or may be faster.

Comment: Yes, we suppose criteria are disjoint (ie pivot table type).